# return x; is not returning an integer value in C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//binary search algo
int bin_search(int n, int a[], int k){ // k is the input value, n is the size of array.

    int s = 0;
    int e = n - 1;
    int m;
    while (s <= e){ // runs while s <= e cuz if s > e, the element doesn't exist
        m = (s + e) / 2;

        if (a[m] == k){
            // mid array ele equals k then we're done, returns mid array index value
            return m;
        }
        else if (a[m] < k){ // if mid array value is smaller than k, array before it is rejected
            s = m + 1;
        }
        else{
            e = m - 1; // if mid array value is larger than k then array after it is rejected.
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){

    int n, arr[3000];
    cout << "how big a sorted array do you want?";
    cin >> n; 

    cout << "enter yer sorted array: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int k;
    cout << "which element do you want to find?";
    cin >> k;
    bin_search(n, arr, k);

    return 0;    
}
```

I wrote this code to return the index of an input value, or return -1 if said integer is not present in the array. The code runs fine, but it doesn't return any value. **Please help.**

Comment: use (print?) the result of `bin_search(n,arr,k);`... don't just simply ignore it.

Comment: When you say it "runs fine", are you saying that the program actually terminates?  When you say it "doesn't return any value", what exactly do you mean?  Your function already returns a value, but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: How can you know it doesn't return anything? You discard the return value. Seems to a beginner mistake: Returning something and printing something to terminal is _not_ the same!

Comment: It doesn't print a value in the console, that's what I meant. By runs fine I meant, no errors.

Comment: @sidpuzzlesquasher "*it doesn't print a value in the console*" - because you are not asking it to. There is no `cout` statement anywhere in this code to print out the return value of `bin_search()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
bin_search(n, arr, k);
```

to something like this

```
cout << "element found at index " << bin_search(n, arr, k) << endl;
```

As churill says, returning something is not the same as printing something. If you want to print something use `cout <<`. If you want to return something use `return`. If you want both then use both.

If you want to calculate something in a function and then print the result in `main` then you need to call the function from `main`, return the value from the function, and print the returned value in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

An example function:

```
int function() {
    return 100;
}
```

When you call `function()` in the `main()` or somewhere else, it does not mean the function will *print* the value but *return* to the assignee or discard if there's no any. In this case, you discard its value by using/assigning it nowhere.

As mentioned in [@john](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205143/11471113)'s answer, you need to call the printing statement in order to display it on the screen.